# Should this -> operator be used in the case where internal class member is invoked in C++?

Tags: c++

My question is about this operator in C++, should we use it as much as possible? I given the following example to show my point:

```
class Abc

{
public:
  int a_;
  void fun();

};

void Abc::fun()
{
  // option 1
   a_ = 3;
  // option 2
  this->a_ = 3;
}
```

In the function class member `fun()`, we can invoke member variables in two ways, one is using `this->` and the other is not using it. So my question is: which practice is encouraged? Thanks.

Comment: It's a matter of style. **Use the style set up in the style guide for your project. Consistency is the most important.** If you're in the position of creating a style guide, use whichever form you prefer. I'd say omitting `this` is more common, but I have no data to back that claim.

Comment: This is surely opinion seeking *so* I wouldn't do it in that situation because it achieves nothing. I do name my parameters the same as the class members; if not using any prefixes `this` is what I use (out of *necessity*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under ordinary circumstances, you're right that you can use both. In such case, it's just a matter of style and the correct thing to do is follow the style guide of your project. Consistency is more important than personal preference in this regard.

However, there are two situations where using `this->` can make a difference. One is when the member function has a parameter with the same name as a member; in such case, the name of the parameter hides the name of the member and you have to use `this->` to refer to the member (first pointed out by @Krypton's answer):

```
void Abc::fun(int a_)
{
  a_ = 3;  // assigns into the parameter
  this->a_ = 3;  // assigns into the data member
}
```

The other situation is when you're working inside a class template and the member is inherited from a base class which depends on template parameters of your class template. In such case, unqualified lookup does not search dependent contexts and so the member would not be found. Using `this->` turns the access into a dependent expression, which will be looked up at instantiation time, and thus resolved to the member correctly. Example:

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
protected:
  T a_;
};


template <class T>
struct Abc : Base<T>
{
  void fun() {
    a_ = 3;  // error, not `a_` in scope
    this->a_ = 3;  // OK, found at instantiation time
  }
};
```

In this situation, an alternative solution exists: make the name visible explicitly:

```
template <class T>
struct Abc : Base<T>
{
protected:
  using Base<T>::a_;

public:
  void fun() {
    a_ = 3;  // OK, found thanks to `using` declaration
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If the variable and the parameter are named the same, using `this` is a must.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int _a;
    void func(int _a) {
        this->_a = _a;
    }

};
```

`this` is also required when referring to a member of a base class that depends on a template parameter of the current class.

Otherwise, it is not necessary to use `this`.

Comment: Also, when referring to a member of a base class that depends on a template parameter of the current class.

Comment: Yeah, this is another case for using `this`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more a matter of style. The use of additional `this->` does not change the produced code.

Though you cannot use operator `this->` in the initialization of class members before the constructor body, like

```
class Abc {
public:
    Abc(int i): /*this-> is incorrect*/i(i) {}
private:
    int i;
};
```

I prefer to use `this->` to have a clear difference with other no-class members.
Then the code like the following is more readable

```
void foo(int i) { }
class Abc {
public:
    Abc(int j) { this->foo(j); }
private:
    void foo (int i) { this->i = i; }
    int i;
};
```

Some people name class data members starting with `m_`, like `m_i`, `m_j`.

Some modern IDEs support semantic syntax highlighting that also helps to distinguish between local variables, class data members, global variables, functions.